# Java Eclipse - naming a field something other than its table column name

Tags: java, jpa

I am brand new to Java, so please be kind.  I am having to add to someone else's working page (working with Eclipse).  I am pulling data from several different servers to pull into one report and I need to make sure that my Key fields all have the same name (**store**, **model**, **serial** - to match up the data from each table with a HashMap).  But each table has a slightly different name for **model** and **serial**, i.e. **modelPK** and **serialPK** in one table, or **keyModel** and **keySerial** in another.  I want each of these fields to be uniform from all tables, so would the Getters/Setters for one of these tables be something like this?

```
@Column(name="keyModel") 
public String getModel() {
    return model;
}

public void setModel(String model) {
    this.model = model;
}

@Column(name="keySerial")
public String getSerial() {
    return serial;
}

public void setSerial(String serial) {
    this.serial = serial;
}
```

It's just the **@Column** that has to have the actual column name, correct?

Comment: I think you're using JPA here and am retagging accordingly; if not, let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> so would the Getters/Setters for one of these tables be something like
>   this?

Yes, the getters and setters look okay.

> It's just the @Column that has to have the actual column name,
>   correct?

Correct. The `name` attribute of the annotation `javax.persistence.Column` must match the actual database column name.

> I want each of these fields to be uniform from all tables

You need to include a Java Persistence API (JPA) implementation such as Hibernate or iBATIS to issue database interaction statements or queries.

Comment: Thank you.  I'm sure I'll have more questions as this goes along!

Comment: @BigRedEO. you are welcome. Please don't forget to upvote and mark the answer that is helpful to you.